# Join and flatten table output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to join 3 tables. The main table is company, if there is 3 companies and 2 roles exists in the role table I want the output to be like this:

```
Company1, Role 1, <iduser>
Company1, Role 2, <iduser>
Company2, Role 1, <iduser>
Company2, Role 2, <iduser>
Company3, Role 1, <iduser>
Company3, Role 2, <iduser>
```

For each role there must be a row for a company. If no user is linked to a role and company then it should just show: **Companyname**, **Rolename**, **null**

Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[role](
    [idrole] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_role] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idrole] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[company](
    [idcompany] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_company] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idcompany] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
    [iduser] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [idcompany] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idrole] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_user] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [iduser] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_user_company] FOREIGN KEY([idcompany])
REFERENCES [dbo].[company] ([idcompany])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_user_company]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_user_role] FOREIGN KEY([idrole])
REFERENCES [dbo].[role] ([idrole])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[user] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_user_role]
GO
```

Test data script:

```
INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[company]
VALUES ('Company 1')

INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[company]
VALUES ('Company 2')

INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[company]
VALUES ('Company 3')


INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[role]
VALUES ('Role 1')

INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[role]
VALUES ('Role 2')
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT roles.name, users.iduser 
FROM [test].[dbo].[role] roles
JOIN [test].[dbo].[user] users ON roles.idrole = users.idrole
JOIN [test].[dbo].[company] company ON company.idcompany = users.idcompany
```

Please advise what approach I can use to achieve this

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that will update post now

Comment: where is user table definition and sample rows?

Comment: Note my updated answer - it didn't answer the question before.

Comment: @mig_08 there seams to be duplicate `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[role]` in the post

Comment: Thanks saw that I missed that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you don't have a relationship between a `Role` and a `Company`, I assume you want every combination of `Role`/`Company`, which is where you use a `CROSS JOIN`.

Then you would `LEFT JOIN` your `User` table on since you want to return null if a user doesn't exist for a given Company-Role.

```
SELECT C.[name], R.[name], U.iduser 
FROM [test].[dbo].[role] R
CROSS JOIN [test].[dbo].[company] C
LEFT JOIN [test].[dbo].[user] U ON U.idrole = R.idrole and U.idcompany = C.idcompany
ORDER BY C.[name], R.[name], U.iduser;
```

Note the use of shorter aliases for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to apply a cross join of the 2 tables the Company and Role tables, afterwards join with the users

```
select * from (
     select idcompany, b.name as coname, a.name, a.idrole
         from company b
         cross join 
         (select idrole, name from role) a
    ) c
    left join dbuser d on c.idcompany = d.idrole
    order by c.coname, c.name
```